# Reverse or Sort a list using Lambda

Tags: list, sorting, lambda, reverse

#Reverse or Sort a list using Lambda
s = ['D','E','C','B','A']

sorted(s,key=lambda s:s)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, anyhow I think this could help:

input:

```
s = ['D','E','C','B','A']
print(s)
s = sorted(s,key=lambda s:s, reverse=True)
print(s)
s = sorted(s,key=lambda s:s, reverse=False)
print(s)
```

output:

```
['D', 'E', 'C', 'B', 'A']
['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```